the question is how to use LogoutView class in django to log out the user and also to redirect him to a specific url
misundersting of the usage of LogoutView based class. I would like to ask for an example in how to use this class to logout the user.
I tried to use pass inside the class but it redirect me to an empty page

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

use this code
from django.contrib.auth import logout

class LogoutView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        logout(request)
        return redirect('login')

